# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'factory_girl_rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, factory-bot

I can't load the gem factory_girl_rails to run my tests properly.
I checked every where but I can't solve it.
Here is my error when I run `spec`:

```
/Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'factory_girl_rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from /Users/qcherifi/Documents/perso/wan/wannatalk.io/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/qcherifi/Documents/perso/wan/wannatalk.io/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/qcherifi/Documents/perso/wan/wannatalk.io/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/qcherifi/Documents/perso/wan/wannatalk.io/spec/spec_helper.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/qcherifi/Documents/perso/wan/wannatalk.io/spec/spec_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `require'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `block in requires='
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `each'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1295:in `requires='
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:109:in `block in process_options_into'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `each'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:108:in `process_options_into'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:105:in `setup'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/qcherifi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Bundle install is ok and here is my gem in /gemfile

```
 group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3'

  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'better_errors'

  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'  
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

/spec/models/participant_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Participant, type: :model do
  it "has a valid factory"
    Factory.create(:participant).should be_valid
  it "is invalid without a name"
  it "returns a participant's full name as a string"
end
```

/spec/factories/participants.rb
    require 'faker'

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :participant do |f|
    f.name {Faker::Name.name}
    f.email {Faker::Internet.email}
    f.password {Faker::Internet.password(8)}
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to install Nodejs on your platform first.

Comment: @BilalMaqsood thanks for your reactivity. I install node js, bundle again and run spec but it's still not running

Comment: Try this instead of using `gem 'factory_girl_rails'` in your gem file use  `gem 'factory_girl'`

Comment: I just found the problem... It was a silly mistake, I created twice the files /support/factory_girl.rb. Now it works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue before, and there are 3 possible reasons of this error:

1. You have your Gemfile duplicated.
2. You have not yet installed node js
3. You have duplicated factory_girl.rb